# SQL Query - Group By Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following query :

```
SELECT directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name, COUNT(user_info.directory_auth_id) as Duplication 
    FROM user_info
GROUP BY directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY directory_auth_id ASC
```

This gives me the desired results and shows me all records that meet the criteria.. What it does not do, is show me ALL the records.. How do I see all records that have been matched.

Thanks,
Boardman.

Comment: Do you understand what `GROUP BY` is for? Because it sounds weird when one first uses a `GROUP BY` then asks to select all rows.

Comment: All records that match what?  And is this in mysql or sql-server, those are 2 different dbs.

Comment: If you're using a COUNT, you HAVE to group. If your only criteria is the count of one field, there's not much you can do to not limit the results. You'll just have to dump the entire data set out without the COUNT.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server only...

To display all rows related only to the `directory_auth_id` that exist more than once, you have to determine which `directory_auth_id` have duplication, then use that resultset as a filter on the main table.

This will accomplish that.

```
;WITH DUPES 
AS
(
    SELECT directory_auth_id
    FROM user_info
    GROUP BY directory_auth_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name
FROM user_info T1
JOIN DUPES T2 ON T1.directory_auth_id = T2.directory_auth_id
```

Comment: Didn't even notice that tag!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the SQL Server tag is correct, the best approach is to use window functions:

```
select ui.*
from (select ui.*, count(*) over (partition by directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name) as cnt
      from user_info ui
     ) ui
where cnt > 1
order by cnt desc, directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support this ANSI standard functionality.  But there are other approaches to solving the problem.

Comment: Is this faster than a CTE approach on large recordsets??  Thanks - I always enjoy reading your answers.

Comment: @JiggsJedi . . . CTEs don't affect performance at all in SQL Server.  There is reason to believe that window functions are more optimized than a `group by`/`join` approach.  There may be other approaches (notably using `not exists`) that might also have good performance.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM user_info where (directory_auth_id,first_name,last_name) in (
SELECT directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name
FROM user_info
GROUP BY directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
ORDER BY directory_auth_id ASC
```

Comment: You can't use multiple columns in an IN() statement.

Comment: Result !!! This gives me exactly the desired results... Always forget abount using the 'IN' statement.

Comment: To check if multiple columns work in in() list, test if the following works.  Different systems may work differently, but this works for me. SELECT *
FROM dual d
WHERE (d.dummy, d.dummy) IN (SELECT dummy, dummy FROM dual);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, this puts your query into an inline view and then joins to it based on the three relevant fields. So you would get all records from user_info that have more than one line for a (directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name) combination.

```
select x.*
  from user_info x
  join (select directory_auth_id,
               first_name,
               last_name,
               count(*) as duplication
          from user_info
         group by directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name
        having count(*) > 1) y
    on x.directory_auth_id = y.directory_auth_id
   and x.first_name = y.first_name
   and x.last_name = y.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for MSSQL:

```
select
  directory_auth_id,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  case when count(user_info.directory_auth_id)
            over (partition by directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name) > 1
       then count(user_info.directory_auth_id)
            over (partition by directory_auth_id, first_name, last_name)
  end as Duplication
from user_info;
```